# Сохранение картинки в UIWebView (IOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c

Здравствуйте!
Как в UIWebView реализовать сохранение картинки при долгом нажатии на нее.Как в Safari. Рылся в документации, ничего не нашел, как будто отключили эту возможность.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего придется использовать немного JavaScript так вам придется работать с HTML в UIWebView. Подобный вопрос уже задавался и на него есть ответ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5163831/uiwebview-enabling-action-sheets-on-img-tags/5607694#5607694 надеюсь знание английского, так как не вижу смысла переписывать весь ответ на русском здесь.

Comment: Я просматривал эту тему,я еще не достаточно опытный чтоб понять все что там написано,если есть что по легче,был бы рад.

Comment: Спасибо за Ваш ответ